# How can I write characters such as § into a file using Python?

Tags: python, file-handling

This is my code for creating the string to be written ('result' is the variable that holds the final text):

```
    fileobj = open('file_name.yml','a+')
    begin = initial+":0 "
    n_name = '"§'+tag+name+'§!"'
    begin_d = initial+"_desc:0 "
    n_desc = '"§3'+desc+'§!"'
    title = ' '+begin + n_name
    descript = ' '+begin_d + n_desc
    result = title+'\n'+descript
    print()
    fileobj.close()
    return result
```

This is my code for actually writing it into the file:

```
    text = writing(initial, tag, name, desc)
    override = inserter(fileobj, country, text)
    fileobj.close()
    fileobj = open('file_name.yml','w+')
    fileobj.write(override)
    fileobj.close()
```

(P.S: Override is a function which works perfectly. It returns a longer string to be written into the file.)

I have tried this with .txt and .yml files but in both cases, instead of §, this is what takes its place: xA7 (I cannot copy the actual text into the internet as it changes into the correct character. It is, however, appearing as xA7 in the file.) Everything else is unaffected, and the code runs fine.

Do let me know if I can improve the question in any way.

Comment: Specify the encoding as UTF-8. `A7` is the representation of § in [ISO/IEC 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (colloquially called "Latin-1"), a very *old* encoding scheme not in common use today, whereas in UTF-8 it would be represented by the 2-byte sequence `C2 A7`. Either your Python implementation or the editor you're opening it in is defaulting to Latin-1 for some (inane) reason.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo little known fact, the first 256 codepoint values in Unicode are the same as the byte values in Latin-1.  In fact if I do `print('\xa7')` I get the desired symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You're running into a problem called *character encoding*. There are two parts to the problem - first is to get the encoding you want in the file, the second is to get the OS to use the same encoding.

The most flexible and common encoding is UTF-8, because it can handle any Unicode character while remaining backwards compatible with the very old 7-bit ASCII character set.  Most Unix-like systems like Linux will handle it automatically.

```
fileobj = open('file_name.yml','w+',encoding='utf-8')
```

You can set your PYTHONIOENCODING environment value to make it the default.

Windows operating systems are a little trickier because they'll rarely assume UTF-8, especially if it's a Microsoft program opening the file.  There's a magic byte sequence called a BOM that will trigger Microsoft to use UTF-8 if it's at the beginning of a file.  Python can add that automatically for you:

```
fileobj = open('file_name.yml','w+',encoding='utf_8_sig')
```

Comment: Ah, thank you very much!